# biblatex: custom fields are not shown

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to add a new entry type with new fields to biblatex. But the fields are not added to the bbl (and so naturally can't be used in the document). I'm probably missing something obvious here, but what?

```
\begin{filecontents}{ufbibstyle.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{uftype}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{uffieldA,uffieldB}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[uftype]{uffieldA,uffieldB}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ufdbx.bib}
@uftype{testdbx,
uffieldA={A},
uffieldB={B},
titleaddon = {something},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[datamodel=ufbibstyle]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{uftype}{% 
  \printfield{uffieldA},\printfield{uffieldB}}
\addbibresource{ufdbx.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{testdbx}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bbl shows then only the titleaddon field:

```
\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nty/global//global/global}
    \entry{testdbx}{uftype}{}
      \field{sortinit}{}
      \field{sortinithash}{495dc9894017a8b12cafa9c619d10c0c}
      \field{titleaddon}{something}
    \endentry
  \enddatalist
\endrefsection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the field names need to be in lowercase. As far as I can see this isn't mentioned in the `biblatex` manual. I guess it should be (or alternatively `biber` should be modified to allow for case insensitive field names in the data model).

I opened an issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/278 for this.

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ufbibstyle.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{uftype}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{uffielda,uffieldb}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[uftype]{uffielda,uffieldb}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ufdbx.bib}
@uftype{testdbx,
uffielda={A},
uffieldb={B},
titleaddon = {something},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[datamodel=ufbibstyle]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{uftype}{% 
  \printfield{uffielda},\printfield{uffieldb}}
\addbibresource{ufdbx.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{testdbx}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I don't think that I would have realized that this is the problem soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it was the only thing I could see was different with working examples! But puzzling, I agree.

Comment: If I had made my example smaller and used only one field it would have worked (and puzzled me even more ...) ;-)